Does China occupy 4000sqkm of territory in the Ladakh region of India?

A September 2024 article in Business Today, China has occupied a land of the size of Delhi in Ladakh quotes a speec from Indian politician Rahul Gandhi


"Well, if you call having Chinese troops in 4,000 square kilometres of our territory handling something well, then maybe we've got Chinese troops occupying land the size of Delhi in Ladakh," Gandhi said while speaking at the National Press Club in Washington DC.
[...]
Gandhi's claims that China has occupied Indian territory in Ladakh are not new. Last year, Rahul Gandhi accused PM Modi of lying to the opposition over the Indo-China border situation in Ladakh. He also repeated his claim that China has snatched Indian territory.

Is it true that China has occupied 4000sqkm of Indian territory in the Ladakh region?
Supplementary question: is this 4000sqkm area that he is talking about part of Aksai Chin or is it outside Aksai Chin?

This probably refers to Aksai Chin, which Wikipedia describes as "administered by China, but claimed by India". Whether it's Indian territory being occupied, or Chinese territory being incorrectly claimed, will be something of a matter of opinion.

@IMSoP: Aksai Chin is 10 times bigger, roughly.

@IMSoP: this is based on something else, more recent "Scroll quoted a January 2023 a senior officer in Leh as writing in a research paper showed India no longer patrol 26 of 65 locations in eastern Ladakh. Leh Senior Superintendent of Police PD Nitya claimed that Indian security forces could no longer access 26 patrolling points between the Karakoram Pass and the Chumur region."

That paper seems to be https://caravanmagazine.in/security/full-text-sp-ladakh-india-lost-access-patrolling-points-china-border I don't see an area quoted, but it does note the loss of some pastures since 2014.

Based on the number of PPs (claimed), that seems to track though. E.g. a decade ago "In 2013, Burtse became a flashpoint when the PLA set up remote camps 18-19 km inside Indian Territory, preventing Indian patrolling from PP10, PP11, PP12 and PP13. The Shyam Saran Report of August 2013 made a chilling revelation of India having lost 640 sq km area due to “area denial” by the PLA."

"Since 2019, the PLA has blocked the Bottleneck area, restricting India’s patrolling limits to PP10 and PP11. The Chinese road construction along Jeevan Nallah towards the south, adjacent to our Murgo post, could potentially cut off the Indian supply line to the DBO at Murgo, like in the case of Galwan. Experts suggest that the Chinese are in control of 600-800 sq km of the southern half of Depsang Plains." https://indianexpress.com/article/columns/india-china-border-dispute-beyond-the-hype-the-reality-of-the-lac-9266802/

However that piece ultimately concludes that "The accusation of losing massive areas, therefore, is a gross exaggeration. Technically, there has been no intrusion on our side of the LAC. The discrepancies have occurred only in the grey-zone patrolling areas due to differences in LAC perception." The whole writeup is rather confusing to me. (Like I'm gonna say, quite a few articles in Indian media.)

@Believeitornot... So it sounds like the claim relies on accepting one definition of the disputed border, and comparing that to the reality on the ground. There is notional agreement that there exists a "Line of Actual Control", but that itself seems not to be fully defined. The only thing we could say reasonably objectively is whether de facto control of territory has changed, but there isn't a clear timeline or baseline in the claim as quoted.

@Believeitornot... Yes, Aksai Chin contested zone is about 35 000 sqkm. India claim is based on Simla convention discussed in 1914 between between Great Britain, China, and Tibet, finally not signed by China. The draft convention specified a frontier known as the Mac Mahon Line from the name of the foreign secretary of British India and the chief British negotiator of the conference at Simla.
